# Copy iPod to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I have an iPod Touch running IOS 6.1.6 (the latest it will support) and am thinking of buying an iPhone 5. The iPod has 32GB but I still have 18GB free and was planning to get a 16GB iPhone.

Can I copy the contents of the iPod to the iPhone?

I probably won't put all the music on the iPhone, and will keep the iPod as a music player.

I will probably need to de-register the iPod, as there are 5 devices on the account (2*iPad, 2*iPod and my wife's iPhone 4).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you sync your iPod with iTunes. If that is the case, once you plug in your iPhone for the first time, you will be able to choose which songs or playlists you want to put on your iPhone.

iTunes is the central hub. You can put it's music on up to 5 of your devices so yes, you will transfer the contents from iTunes to iPhone.